# How to create a bar plot with dynamic variables for each group and stand error bars included?

Tags: r, bar-chart, candlestick-chart

I try to create a dynamic bar chart with an exact same format as this [model graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvAW.png) here using R. Unfortunately, my teacher did not provide us with the R codes for the model graph and therefore this dynamic bar chart is taking me hours and hours and I still cannot make it exactly the same as the model graph.
The data I used to create the dynamic bar chart is here:

```
tidyadhd <- structure(list(voltage = c(9.5, 10, 9.2, 6, 9, 11, 9, 9.2, 8, 
9, 11, 9, 8.2, 8, 9, 9, 6, NA, 9.5, 9, 7.1, 9.3, 9, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 
9.3, 9, 8.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3, 8.2, 9, 9.3, NA, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3, 
9, 9.5, 9, 9.2, 9.3, 9, 9.5, 9, 9, 9, 9.3, 8, 7, 8, 5.1, 4.3, 
4.5, 5.3, 4.5, 5.1, 4.3, 4.5, 5.3, 4.5, 5.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 5.3, 
6.4, 5, 8), state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Rest", "Cue"), class = "factor"), treatment = c("placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", 
"placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "placebo", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", 
"ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin", "ritalin"), patient = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L)), .Names = c("voltage", "state", "treatment", "patient"
), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = "data.frame")
```

and an image of a part of the output table is shown in this image here:
[image: two-way ANOVA table]

Can someone teach me how to create a dynamic bar plot with an exact same format as this model graph please? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
tidyadhd %>%
  group_by(treatment, state) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(treatment, state, n) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(voltage), funs(mean, sd = sd), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(se = sd / sqrt(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(treatment, mean, group = state, fill = state)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "white")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, I have another question, what is %>% means? Because I've put the code into R, but it comes up with "could not find function %>%"

Comment: `%>`%` is a pipe operator. Make sure that you run `library(tidyverse)` first as in my code.

Comment: sorry, but it just keeps coming up with this:                 

-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: utils::packageVersion(x)
  error: package ‘tibble’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Comment: You have to install `tibble` first. If not all `tidyverse` packages are installed, you can replace `library(tidyverse)` with `library(dplyr);  library(ggplot2)`.

Comment: Thanks you! It works in my R studio now, and I have a very last question: I want to change the name of my y-axis label "mean" into "voltage(μV)", how and where should I do that?

Comment: Add `ylab("voltage(μV)")` after `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9))`

Comment: Thank you very much! I've completed the graph, you're so helpful! Thanks again.